# grizzly + jersey + websocket - not accepting connections

Tags: java, websocket, jersey, grizzly

I have a Web Service running on top of Grizzly in a standalone application.

The Grizzly HTTP server is instantiated as follows:

```
    this.httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri);

    WebappContext applicationContext = new WebappContext("test", "/test");

    ServletRegistration registration = applicationContext.addServlet("jersey", ServletContainer.class);
    registration.addMapping("/*");
    registration.setInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, MyApplicationService.class.getName());
    applicationContext.deploy(httpServer);

    WebSocketAddOn webSocketAddon = new WebSocketAddOn();
    httpServer.getListeners().forEach(listener -> {
        listener.registerAddOn(webSocketAddon);
    });

    WebSocketEngine.getEngine().register("/ws", "/notifications", myNotificationService);
```

Problem: my notification service is not accepting any web socket connection.

But if I change:

```
    // factory from org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver
    this.httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri);
```

By:

```
    // factory from org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server
    this.httpServer = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(null, 8084);
```

Then my service does accept web socket connections.

I don't understand why. What's the difference between both?

Comment: For my general knowledge, what websocket implementation are you using? When I saw grizzly, I thought you were using the GlassFish-like application server but it doesn't seem so. Meanwhile, I'm trying to understand the relationship between web services and websocket in your example. Merci!

Comment: I'm using Grizzly as the HTTP server for my micro-services running in a standalone Java SE application. Grizzly provides a Web Socket implementation (not a JSR 356 one though). Web Services are used for the client to server communication (queries and commands) while the Web Sockets are used for notification of domain events.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. I may come back in few months, if you don't mind, as we have a Java SE application + websocket development planned for next year.

Answer (score 2):

It had to be simple...

Replacing

```
this.httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri);
```

by

```
this.httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, false);
```

Solves the issue.

The HTTP server was auto-started before it got a chance to be configured with the Web Socket add-on.